# What does the outgoing SMTP request from ActionMailer look like?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp, actionmailer, faraday

Some background: I'm working on an app that sends out emails via ActionMailer in Ruby on Rails, but I need my Heroku-hosted app to sit behind a static IP range to be whitelisted by the SMTP relay server it's sending through. For this I've included a Heroku addon called Fixie, which gives my app a static IP range and can be configured for requests through gems like Faraday.

My main question is this: how can I figure out and/or log this outgoing request that is made by ActionMailer when I call #mail? I'd like to know where this is request is being made and more about it so that I can instead make this request using the Faraday gem, which supports using Fixie's proxy IP.

Edit: Upon more research, it seems like I need to set up a SOCKS5 proxy rather than a simple HTTP(S) proxy, as this outbound request is done using SMTP. Still unsure on my original question though.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @jj57347, did you find a solution? I have *exactly* the same issue. I'd appreciate if you could help!

Answer (score 0):

To set up action mailer on Heroku my standard configuration looks like this

```
# config/environments/production.rb
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'https://www.example.com' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain => 'heroku.com'
  }
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Now I use the Heroku ad on [SENDGRID](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/sendgrid) and it adds the **SENDGRID_USERNAME** and **SENDGRID_PASSWORD** to your Config Vars

Now I don't do anything special on the mailer but I will add one for the example

```
# app/mailers/example_mailer.rb
class ExampleMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'donotreply@example.com'
  default cc:   'cc@example.com'
  default bcc:  'bcc@example.com'

  layout 'mailer'

  def some_email(example_id)
    @example = Example.find(example_id)
    mail(
        :to =>   'user@example.com',
        :subject =>" SUBJECT ",
        :body => "This can and should be moved to a view like app/view/example_mailr/some_email.html.erb"
    )
  end
end
```

I hope that this helps you out